# Firebase an not instantiate value of type from String value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class net.we4x4.we4x4.userInformation] from String value; no single-String constructor/factory method

This error is confusing me, i've tried to follow several instructions provided on the firebase Docs, such as this one : https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html

and another one on querying data, also another tutorial here : 
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-android-tutorial-writing-firebase-data/

and i was not able to solve the problem, in a proper way, simply what i am trying to do is get the data from this JASON :

```
  {
 "data" : {
"ratingPic" : 0,
"ratingVClip" : 36
 },
"users" : {
"3c42f867-8c3a-423b-89e8-3fb777ab76f8" : {
  "email" : "k@k.com",
  "username" : "kkk"
},
"50347968-cedb-4648-8025-f737fea8d4c9" : {
  "email" : "a@a.com",
  "username" : "aaa"
  }
 }
}
```

By a singleValueEventListner of childEventListner, i still the same error, i've created a seperate crass to deal with extracting the information from firebase :

```
public class userInformation {
private String email;
private String username;

public userInformation(){

}

public userInformation(String username){
    this.username = username;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
```

}

And this is the confusing part, as was suggested by the good ppl on firebase community, that i do not need a setter, but when i dont put a setter in this class i get the error, and i only avoided getting the error with this construct of the class which only extract a single string, and when i add more strings i still get the error, so when i add:

```
    public userInformation(String username,  String email){
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
}
```

i get the error, in the below stack trace ?

my main method is :

```
     public void readingData() {
    Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://wi4x4.firebaseio.com/users/" + UserID);
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                userInformation userInformation = postSnapshot.getValue(userInformation.class);
                String username = userInformation.getUsername();
                String email = userInformation.getEmail();
                usernameDisplay.setText(email);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            firebaseError.getMessage();
        }
    });
}
```

*** The same Error accrue with addChildEventListner;

```
     public void readingData(){
    Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://wi4x4.firebaseio.com/users/" + UserID);
    Query queryRef = ref.orderByChild("email");
    queryRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String email) {
            // Map<String, Objects> extractedEmail = (Map<String, Objects>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            userInformation userInformation = dataSnapshot.getValue(userInformation.class);
            email = userInformation.getEmail();
            usernameDisplay.setText(email);
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChild) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChild) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

I apologize for the long post, but i am trying to provide as much info in order to get some help understand the confusion here .

```
03-26 07:30:42.654 8560-8560/net.we4x4.we4x4 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: net.we4x4.we4x4, PID: 8560
  com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type
     at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:183)
     at net.we4x4.we4x4.MainActivity$2.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:112)
     at com.firebase.client.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:45)
     at com.firebase.client.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:45)
     at com.firebase.client.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:38)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class net.we4x4.we4x4.userInformation] from String value; no single-String constructor/factory method
     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator._createFromStringFallbacks(StdValueInstantiator.java:428)
     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromString(StdValueInstantiator.java:299)
     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromString(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1056)
     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:136)
     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:123)
     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2888)
     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2034)
     at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:181)
     at net.we4x4.we4x4.MainActivity$2.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:112) 
     at com.firebase.client.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:45) 
     at com.firebase.client.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:45) 
     at com.firebase.client.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:38) 
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reading a single user object, so it doesn't have children:

```
public void readingData() {
  Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://wi4x4.firebaseio.com/users/" + UserID);
  ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            userInformation userInformation = postSnapshot.getValue(userInformation.class);
            String username = userInformation.getUsername();
            String email = userInformation.getEmail();
            usernameDisplay.setText(email);
        }
```

So that for loop will iterator over the **child properties** of the user, `email` and `username`. Those cannot be deserialized into a `userInformation` object.

The solution is simply to not loop:

```
public void readingData() {
  Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://wi4x4.firebaseio.com/users/" + UserID);
  ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        userInformation userInformation = dataSnapshot.getValue(userInformation.class);
        String username = userInformation.getUsername();
        String email = userInformation.getEmail();
        usernameDisplay.setText(email);
    }
```

Comment: Frank, thank you that definitely solved the problem with addValueEventListener, but i assume it should work with addChildEventListener ? but i get the same Error, when i use the same userInformation class with the other method ? i added the method syntax i used in the main post

Comment: If you use ``addChildEventListener``, then it will fire once for **each** of the **children**. In this case _email_ then again for _username_. This is probably not the behaviour you want.  Suggest you probably want to create a listener to read all users data, not just a single user, so back up the tree a notch by using: ``Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://wi4x4.firebaseio.com/users/);"``, then use a for loop to iterate through each _user_, just as you tried earlier.  (If you really do want to create a listener to monitor just one user, then use ``ValueEventListener`` as you are already.)