# Unable to populate recycler viiew from Firebase DB

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Though this question was answered a few times, any of the answers were not able to solve my problem.

I have a firebase DB which only has two key-value pairs. Below is the json.

```
{
   "route" : {
   "routeA" : {
   "stop" : "Street 1",
   "time" : "11:00 PM"
  }
 }
}
```

The following is my code to get data from firebase DB

```
  recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    rootRef = new Firebase("https://listrecycler.firebaseio.com/route/");
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    itemsRef = rootRef.child("route B");
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "crossed itemRef", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Route, RouteViewHolder>(Route.class, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, RouteViewHolder.class, itemsRef) {
        @Override
        public void populateViewHolder(RouteViewHolder routeViewHolder, Route route, int i) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "reached populate view holder", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(TAG, "populateViewHolder: " + route);
            routeViewHolder.place.setText(route.getStop());
            routeViewHolder.time.setText(route.getTime());
        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

}

public static class RouteViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView place;
    TextView time;

    public RouteViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        place = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        time = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
    }
}
```

This is the simple code without any recyclerview as suggested by Frank. The code is working fine. No Jackson errors

```
 rootRef = new Firebase("https://listrecycler.firebaseio.com/route");

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    itemsRef = rootRef.child("routeA");

    itemsRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Route routeDetails = dataSnapshot.getValue(Route.class);
            String stop = routeDetails.getStop();
            String time = routeDetails.getTime();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Stop Name:"+ stop+"Time:"+time, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: "+dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

This following is my POJO

```
public class Route {
public String stop;
public String time;

public Route() {
}

public Route(String stop, String time) {
    this.stop = stop;
    this.time = time;
}

public String getStop() {
    return stop;
}

public void setStop(String stop) {
    this.stop = stop;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}
}
```

The issue with the code is that the Jackson is unable to deserialize the data sent by Firebase when I am using the POJO. When I use a simple String class instead of the Route POJO, the data being perfectly written into the recycler view item. Below is the error log

```
05-06 22:38:03.724 30051-30051/abc.com.example.vijsu.listrecyclerfirebase E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                        Process: abc.com.example.vijsu.listrecyclerfirebase, PID: 30051
                                                                                        com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type
                                                                                            at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:183)
                                                                                            at com.firebase.ui.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.parseSnapshot(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:161)
                                                                                            at com.firebase.ui.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:150)
                                                                                            at com.firebase.ui.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:190)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5465)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5498)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4735)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4611)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1988)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1384)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1347)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3026)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2903)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1457)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.access$400(RecyclerView.java:147)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:285)
                                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603)
                                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                         Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class abc.com.example.vijsu.listrecyclerfirebase.Route] from String value; no single-String constructor/factory method
                                                                                            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator._createFromStringFallbacks(StdValueInstantiator.java:428)
                                                                                            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromString(StdValueInstantiator.java:299)
                                                                                            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromString(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1056)
                                                                                            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:136)
                                                                                            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:123)
                                                                                            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2888)
                                                                                            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2034)
                                                                                            at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:181)
                                                                                            at com.firebase.ui.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.parseSnapshot(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:161) 
                                                                                            at com.firebase.ui.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:150) 
                                                                                            at com.firebase.ui.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:190) 
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5465) 
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5498) 
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4735) 
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4611) 
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1988) 
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1384) 
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1347) 
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574) 
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3026) 
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2903) 
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1457) 
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.access$400(RecyclerView.java:147) 
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:285) 
                                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858) 
                                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670) 
                                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603) 
                                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I have flushed the data from Firebase checking to ensure that the String names in POJO and Firebase DB match multiple times. I understand I'm missing something  related to the POJO but not able to figure it out.

But the error still exists with recycler view !!!

Comment: We've been getting a few cases of this exception recently. E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36231398/. If that is not the cause, can you replace the picture of your JSON with the actual JSON, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase dashboard. In addition: can you isolate the problem in a piece of code that doesn't require a `RecyclerView`? I'm pretty sure you'll be able to reproduce it with a single `ref.getValue(Route.class)` and that will make it easier to help you.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Attached the JSON as u hav asked.The simple code without recycler views works very fine. But I need recycler view in my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The silliest mistake was that I forgot that a recycler view takes a list of properties and I had multiple properties (stop and time) to display in one row. So i just need to fetch the **routeA** and give it to firebasui to display. I went into deeper level while getting the data upto routeA and the firebaseui was not able to recognize the properties. Only one level query upto **route** is enough to display the **stop** and **time** properties in single row.

Wrote it as a separate answer so that it helps the guys like me who are ignorant of little but important things. This concept is also a part of the answer posted by @Frank van Puffelen to one of the similar.

Answer (score 4):

The error mentions this

> Can not instantiate value of type ... Route... no single-String constructor/factory method

So you might want to add one

```
public class Route {

    public String stop;
    public String time;

    public Route() {}

    public Route(String routeJSON) { 
        // TODO: Parse out JSON object
        // call setters...
    }

    public Route(String stop, String time) {
        this.stop = stop;
        this.time = time;
    }
```

Comment: cricket_007 I have just removed the second parameter from the parameterized constructor and everything works fine making it a single string constructor. But the problem is I need the paramaterized constructor to push data to the firebase DB.     public Route(String stop) {
        this.stop = stop;
    }

Comment: One more thing I found is that whichever property is present in the single string construct, only that value is being is extracted from the JSON. The other value is returning null.

Comment: That's because you have to set **both** strings... You are getting a JSON string with both values in it. That is what I meant by `routeJSON` and "call setters". You need to use Jackson to convert that string into a JSONObject